# Serial Communication Between Two Arduino Boards

Tags: arduino, serial-communication

I'm trying to do serial communication between two Arduinos.

I used this [circuit diagram](https://iotguider.in/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/Serial-communication-between-Arduino.png) and this code works perfectly;

```
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  if (Serial.available()) {
    switch(Serial.read())
    { case 'A':
      digitalWrite(13,HIGH);
      break;
      case 'B':
      digitalWrite(13,LOW);
      break;
    }
}
}
```

But I don't want to use switch-case. I want to use if conditions. I'm trying this code;

```
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  if (Serial.available()) {
    if(Serial.read()=='A')
    {
      digitalWrite(13,HIGH);
    }
    else if(Serial.read()=='B')
    {
      digitalWrite(13,LOW);
    }
}
}
```

But it doesn't work. My question is; why is works with switch-case but not with if conditions. Where is my fault? Can you fix it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tried both codes and I think that the problem is data reading. Here follows my test codes.
Sender code:

```
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
}
void loop() {
  Serial.println("A"),
  delay(1000);
  Serial.println("B"),
  delay(1000);
}
```

Receiver code:

```
int data;
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(13, OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {
if (Serial.available()) {
    data = Serial.read();
    if(data=='A')
    {
      digitalWrite(13,HIGH);
    }
    else if(data=='B')
    {
      digitalWrite(13,LOW);
    }
  }
}
```

When you try to test data read from serial communication it's always a good practice to save the buffer to a variable and then do all the control stuff. This way you can trust that the data is always the same. Here a more rigid explanation.
When you do an if statement like the one that you've tested you don't actually test the same value in one loop.`if(Serial.read()=='A')` and `else if(Serial.read()=='B')` actually tests two different readings from the serial in two different times. When you do instead a single reading with `data = Serial.read()` and you compare the reading stored in a variable with expected value like  `data == 'A'` the reading is done only one time and "remain the same" through all the loop.
Note that the comparison it's done with char ('') not ("") in my test.

Hope I've helped solving your problem. Let us know it works for you

Comment: thanks dude, it works! But I have a 1 more question. This works perfect only if we send only 1 character like `"A"`. If I want to send `"Arda"` from sender, and examine this string in receiver; how can I do ?

Comment: Sender: ```void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
Serial.println("Alpha");
delay(1000);
Serial.println("Beta");
delay(1000);
}``` The receiver code: ```String data;
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(13, OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {
    while(Serial.available()){
    data = Serial.readStringUntil('\r');
    //delay(100);
    Serial.println(data);
    if(data=="Alpha")
    {
      digitalWrite(13,HIGH);
    }
    else if(data=="Beta")
    {
      digitalWrite(13,LOW);
    }
  }
}``` Variable need to be String. '\r' is the char @ string end.

Comment: it is not entering the if conditions

Comment: I've tested that and works with no problem for me with both codes(sender and receiver)

Comment: Maybe check the sender part of your solution and see if you've a delay so that the receiver has the time to read and execute the code.